# Incorrect syntax in SQL script when I try to run it on the server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate-functions

I have this SQL script that I need to run. It creates an aggregate that I need.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE [dbo].[MLRXYZ]
  (@x1 [float], @x2 [float], @x3 [float], @x4 [float])
RETURNS [xml]
  EXTERNAL NAME [dws.MultipleLinearRegression].[dws.MLRXYZ]
```

When I run it on my computer locally it runs fine.

However I need to connect remotely to a server and run it on the sql server installed on it.
I copy past the script and try to execute it I get this syntax error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Both my pc and the server have SQL Server 2008 R2

Anyone has an idea of the problem? Why is it working locally and not on the server?

Thanks a lot